# !MODULE NOT FOUND" When running node index.js w/npm

Tags: vscode-code-runner

I've borrowed a code off Github, but when I try to run the code, this error comes up:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ihate\Desktop\hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/sha1'
- C:\Users\Ihate\Desktop\hashlips_art_engine\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ihate\Desktop\hashlips_art_engine\src\main.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Ihate\\Desktop\\hashlips_art_engine\\src\\main.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Ihate\\Desktop\\hashlips_art_engine\\index.js'
  ]
```

I don't quite understand this error even after an hour or so of research. I can confirm that those two files do exist in the correct location.

Please ask questions if this isn't clear or if you need information, I'll try to get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to download those modules before running the app?

Comment: Turns out my NPM install was somehow broken, so all I had to do was run 'npm audit fix'